# What is the name of this theorem? I do not know how to type some symbols in google.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, bounded-variation

In my textbook, the following theorem is proved.
But I do not understand it. So I am finding some other documents make me understand the theorem. Could someone let me know this theorem's name? Since I don't know the name, it is too difficult to find this theorem.

---

$f$ is a real-valued function on $[a, b]$.

$\Gamma$ is a partition of $f$ on $[a, b]$.
$$
\Gamma=\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=0}^N, \quad x_0(=a) \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \cdots \lt x_N(=b)
$$

$|\Gamma|$ is a norm of the partition $\Gamma$.
$$
|\Gamma|=\max_{i\in\left\{1, 2, \cdots, N\right\}}\left\{x_i-x_{i-1}\right\}
$$

$S_\Gamma$ is a sum of the absolute of the differences of $f$.
$$
S_\Gamma=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left|f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})\right|
$$

$V$ is variance of $f$.
$$
V=\sup_{\Gamma}S_\Gamma
$$

---

### Theorem

If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $\displaystyle V=\lim_{\left|\Gamma\right|\to0}S_\Gamma$.

That is, given $M$ satisfying $M<V$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\displaystyle S_\Gamma>M$ with $\left|\Gamma\right|<\delta$.

---

Actually, I don't know why this theorem is referred in textbook.

In my opinion, $\displaystyle V=\lim_{\left|\Gamma\right|\to0}S_\Gamma$ is sure and trivial for the following two reasons:

1. The more finely the partition is split, the larger $\displaystyle S_\Gamma$ is; that is, $S_\Gamma \uparrow$ as $|\Gamma|\to0$
2. $\displaystyle V=\sup_\Gamma S_\Gamma$.

---

Comment: Most theorems lack names; I've seen theorems sort of like this but can't remember that they had a name.  I am guessing that $S_\Gamma$ is some sort of Riemann sum but the details of how it's defined may be needed to reason about it.

Comment: Without telling us the definition of $S_\Gamma$, it remains impossible to answer the question.

Comment: I edited my post. I added definitions of symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you said were true the theorem would indeed be obvious. But it's  not true that $S_\Gamma$ increases as $|\Gamma|$ decreases.

Say $[a,b]=[0,5]$. Say $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=f(5)=0$, $f(4)=1$. Consider the two partitions $\Gamma_1 = (0,4,5)$, $\Gamma_2=(0,1,2,3,5)$. Then $|\Gamma_2|<|\Gamma_1|$ but $S_{\Gamma_2}<S_{\Gamma_1}$.

**Edit:** Of course it *is* true that if $\Gamma'$ is a *refinement* of $\Gamma$ then $S_{\Gamma'}\ge S_\Gamma$. That's crucial in proving the theorem:

Say $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $M<V$. Choose a partition $\Gamma_1$ with $$S_{\Gamma_1}>M.$$ Say $\Gamma_1$ has $N$ points (including the endpoints).

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so that $|s-t|<\delta$ implies $|f(s)-f(t)|<\epsilon/(3N)$. Say $\Gamma_2$ is a partition with $|\Gamma_2|<\delta$. Let $\Gamma$ be the partition obtained by using all the points in $\Gamma_1$ and all the points in $\Gamma_2$. Then $\Gamma$ is a refinement of $\Gamma_1$, so $$S_{\Gamma}\ge S_{\Gamma_1}>M.$$

But $S_{\Gamma_2}$ is the same as $S_\Gamma$, except for $N$ places where $S_{\Gamma}$ includes two terms $$|f(x_j)-f(y_k)|+|f(y_k)-f(x_{j+1})|$$and $S_{\Gamma_1}$ includes just the one term $$|f(x_j)-f(x_{j+1})|$$

Each of those "error terms" is less than $\epsilon/(3N)$. So
$$|S_{\Gamma_2}-S_\Gamma|<\epsilon,$$hence $$S_{\Gamma_2}>M-\epsilon.$$

Comment: Ah, you gave me a good intuition. Thank you, but still in your case, $S_\Gamma$ approaches to $V$ as $|\Gamma|$ goes to zero, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course it does! I didn't say the theorem was false - your explanation for why it's trivial is incorrect, is all. (That's _if_ $f$ is continuous, as in the theorem you stated. The theorem is false for discontinuous functions...)

Comment: Ah-ha! I couldn't agree more. You are right.

Comment: My book, "Measure and Integral" by Wheeden and Zygmund, includes the proof of the above theorem. However, it is pure Alice in Wonderland. Can you recommend some other proofs? If you don't mind, please let me know some links helpful for me(very noob).

Comment: I added a sketch of a proof. I don't know the book, but I doubt that what I wrote is really any different.

Comment: About key words that you are asking for, here is one: "Total Variation" abbreviated in TV. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation ; you will find many articles on the subject (TV is a very active research subject in image enhancement in particular)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read answer and TV as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you, again. However, I failed to understand from $S_{\Gamma_2}$ is the same as $S_{\Gamma}$. Can you explain how it comes from?

Comment: @Danny_Kim Consider an example. Maybe $\Gamma_1$ is given by $a=y_0<y_1<y_2=b$, while $\Gamma_2$ is given by $a=x_0<\dots<x_9=b$. Now $\Gamma$ is the union of the two; the point $y_1$ must fit between to successive points $x_j$ and $x_{j+1}$. Maybe $\Gamma$ is given by $a=x_0<\dots<x_4<y_1<x_5<\dots<x_9=b$. Now write down what $S_\Gamma$ and $S_{\Gamma_2}$ are; you see they are the same except that $S_\Gamma$ includes the two terms $|f(x_4)-f(y_1)|+|f(y_1)-f(x_5)|$ where $S_{\Gamma_2}$ has just the one term $|f(x_4)-f(x_5)|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah, I almost got it. It's all because of you. I appreciate your answer and kind comments.